# Sending an int array via MPI_Send

Tags: c, mpi, openmpi

I'm new to MPI and i would like to send an `int` array via `MPI_Send` to another process.

```c
// Code example
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int * array;
    int tag=1;
    int size;
    int rank;
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Init (&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);
    MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
    
    if (rank == 0)
    {
        array = malloc (10 * sizeof(int)); // Array of 10 elements
        if (!array) // error checking
        {
            MPI_Abort (MPI_COMM_WORLD,1);
        }
        MPI_Send(&array,10,MPI_INT,1,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    
    if (rank == 1)
    {
        MPI_Recv (&array,10,MPI_INT,0,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
        // more code here
    }
    
    MPI_Finalize();
    // More code here
```

I would like to ask three things.

1. Is this a SAFE way to send an array to another process-rank?
2. Is this a syntax wise correct usage of `MPI_Send()` and `MPI_Recv()`?
3. Is there a better way to send and receive an array without too much trouble?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend to revisit the basics about pointers in C before jumping in MPI.

Comment: `MPI_Recv()` does not allocate the array for you. both `MPI_Send()` and `MPI_Recv()` needs a pointer to the data, and not the address of a pointer to the data.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are going to dynamically allocate the array, the send and receive would be:

`MPI_Send(array,10,MPI_INT,1,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD);`

and

`MPI_Recv (array,10,MPI_INT,0,tag,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);`

(Note that array is `array` and not `&array`)

As suggested in the comments, your understanding of MPI seems fine however refreshing your usage of C pointers may help.

Edit: As mentioned by Gilles, all processes receiving data into an array need to have memory allocated for them too. (Maybe send the size of the data first so the receiver knows how big to allocate the array? There are other ways to do this however that is a simple explanation)

Comment: `array` must be allocated on the receiver too!

Comment: Good shout Gilles!